# Gradle Build failing after adding image_picker plugin in flutter app

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter, build.gradle

When I run the application without adding image picker as a dependency, it works fine. But when I add the plugin and run, it is giving me gradle build failed error.

```
Resolving dependencies...                                    5.0s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of image_picker will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.

         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\142.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\118.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\94.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\124.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\136.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\157.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\103.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\163.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\151.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\127.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\166.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\139.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\97.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\115.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\160.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\169.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\106.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\154.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\148.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\112.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\172.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\133.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\109.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\91.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\121.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\145.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, D:\fluuter_projects\motor_app_demo\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         23.7s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to Android X Support...
Simple Solution Avoiding AndroidX and rollback to older version
dependencies:
image_picker: 0.4.12+1

or

Migrate Flutter app to AndroidX
Import your Flutter app into Android Studio so that the IDE can parse the Android code following the steps in Editing Android code in Android Studio with full IDE support.

Follow the instructions for Migrating to AndroidX.

https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: AndroidX Compatibility document was helpful.